# Module not found - polyfill

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
[ng] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
[ng]
[ng] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
[ng]    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'

installed
npm install --save-dev crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify url buffer process
still same error occurs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on ionic angular project with truffle. While using web3 to connect to metamask and contract this error occurs.Currently using these versions Truffle v5.6.6 (core: 5.6.6)
Ganache v7.5.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.21.2
Web3.js v1.7.4 webpack:5.75.0

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI : 5.4.16

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.7.1

System:

   NodeJS : v14.21.2
   npm    : 6.14.17
   OS     : Linux 5.4